# Help with the question if the following is a linear transformation or not

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am new to Linear Algebra, and am asked to check if the following transformation is linear. In principle, I know the criteria to check for: T(v+v')=T(v)+T(v') and c(Tv)=T(cv), where v is a vector, c is any scalar, and T is the transformation. However, when applying these to the following transformation, I get completely lost because of the complexity of the actual transformation. I am thinking there must be a shortcut I am not seeing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

$T:M^C_{nxn}\to M^C_{nxn}$ defined by $T(X)=2X+(1+3i)\bar X^t$.  $M^C_{nxn}$ is a linear space over **C**.

There is an additional comment stating that we should refer to the general element of matrix $X$ as $x_{ij}$, while referring to the general element of matrix $\bar X$ as $\bar x_{ij}$

Thank you!

Comment: Try writing the statement and proof for $n=2$. With $2 \times 2$ matrices you  won't need any indices for the "general element". Then work on the general case. You can [edit] the question to show us how far you get before you're stuck.

Comment: I fail to see why the subexpression $S: X \mapsto \bar{X}$ should be linear. $S(\lambda X) = \bar{\lambda} S(X)$, so it isn't linear. Anyway, for OP it's probably easier to prove linearity of $X\mapsto 2X$, $S$, $X\mapsto X^t$ and $X\mapsto (1+3i)X$ separately and then apply "addition of linear functions is linear".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Apply the rules mechanically:

$$2(X+X')+(1+3i)\overline{(X+X')}^t
\\=2X+2X'+(1+3i)(\bar X+\bar X')^t
\\=2X+2X'+(1+3i)(\bar X^t+\bar X'^t)
\\=2X+2X'+(1+3i)\bar X+(1+3i)\bar X'
\\=(2X+(1+3i)\bar X)+(2X'+(1+3i)\bar X').$$

There is nothing really complicated.

You may also just state that

- averaging is a linear operation,
- transposition is a linear operation,
- scalar multiplicationis a linear operation,
- addition is a linear operation.

Proving each of theses statements separately is at your reach.

---

**Update:**

I didn't see that the overline denotes conjugation. Then

- complex conjugation is *not* is a linear operation.

Because $$\overline{aX}=\overline a\overline X\ne a\overline X.$$

Comment: But its not linear right?

Comment: @OlofRubin: why not ? I just explained that it is.

Comment: $T(iX)\neq iT(X)$ in general?

Comment: @OlofRubin: how so ? Please substantitate.

Comment: $T(iI) = 2iI-i(1+3i)I = iI+3I$ while $iT(I) = 2iI+i(1+3i)I = 3iI-3I$?

Comment: @OlofRubin: ouch, does the over bar denote complex conjugation ?

Comment: That is how i interpreted it but I'm not sure

Comment: @YvesDaoust
Thank you for your help!
So for future reference: if there is complex conjugation involved, I can simply cut the whole process short and conclude the transformation is not linear?

Comment: @dalta: any nonlinear intermediate operation can indeed break linearity.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation clearly satisfies $T(X+Y) = T(X)+T(Y)$ right? Also if $\alpha$ is real then $T(\alpha X) = \alpha T(X)$ is trivial. However the final property we need for linearity is that $T(iX) = iT(X)$ for then we can conclude that $T((\alpha+i\beta)X) = \alpha T(X)+i\beta T(X)$ for real $\alpha,\beta$. We therefore consider

$$2iX+i(1+3i)\bar{X}^t=i(2X+(1+3i)\bar{X}^t) = iT(X) =^? T(iX) =  2iX-i(1+3i)\bar{X}^t$$

If we consider the identity matrix $I$ then is it true that

$$2iI+i(1+3i)I =^? 2iI-i(1+3i)I$$